# Error convirtiendo grados Celsius a Farenheit ejercicio de C

Tags: c

Convertir grados **celsius** a grados **fahrenheit**

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
        int g_c
        int g_f = 32; 
        int mult = 0;
        printf("Digite el numero de grados celsius: ");
        scanf("%i",&g_c,);
        mult = g_c * g_f;
        printf("La conversion es: %i",mult);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Joseph,  te invito a modificar tu pregunta en base a [ask], agrega una explicación en el cuerpo de la misma para que sea bien recibida en el sitio y obtengas excelentes respuestas. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Tenías algunos errores de sintaxis y algo mal en la lógica debes multiplicar los grados celsius por 1,8 y luego sumarle 32 utilice esta [guia](https://www.saberespractico.com/ciencia/como-pasar-de-grados-celsius-a-fahrenheit-y-viceversa/):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int g_c;
    int g_f = 32; 
    int mult = 0;
    printf("Digite el numero de grados celsius: ");
    scanf("%i",&g_c);
    mult = (g_c * 1.8) + g_f;
    printf("La conversion es: %i",mult);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Recuerda que en C, [todas las sentencias terminan con un punto y coma.](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Primer_programa_en_C)

2) También que la función [scanf()](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=911:pedir-datos-por-teclado-con-c-funcion-scanf-codigos-de-formato-tipos-int-long-double-char-string-cu00522f&catid=82&Itemid=210) que nos ayuda a pedir datos a través del teclado tiene dos argumentos ( `scanf("%codigoFormato", &nombreVariableQueAlmacenaLaEntrada);` ) y no 3 como lo estas realizando (los argumentos que usan las funciones se separan por ","):

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(){ 
        int g_c       //*ERROR 1)
        int g_f = 32; 
        int mult = 0;
        printf("Digite el numero de grados celsius: ");
        scanf("%i",&g_c,); //*ERROR 2)
        mult = g_c * g_f;
        printf("La conversion es: %i",mult);
        return 0;
    }
```

3) Ahora la formula para [convertir de grados Celsius a Farenheit](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/temperature/celsius-to-fahrenheit.html) es:

```
°F = °C × 9/5 + 32
```

Por lo tanto el valor de entrada lo debes multiplicar por 9/5 y sumar la variable que tiene el valor de 32 (`g_f`):

```
mult = (g_c * 9/5) + g_f;
```

Realiza estos cambios para que tu programa funcione correctamente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        int g_c;
            int g_f = 32; //* 1)
            int mult = 0;

            printf("Digite el numero de grados celsius: ");
            scanf("%i",&g_c); //* 2)

            mult = (g_c * 9/5) + g_f; //* 3)    
            printf("La conversion es: %i",mult);

            return 0;
    }
```